# How many backup copies are taken of a SQL Azure Database when using "Automated Export"?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have set up a automated backup of my live V11 SQL Azure DB via "Automated Export" each night, and is retained for 7 days.

I am just doing a security audit, and one of the questions is :

```
How many copies of data are backed-up?
```

Now I know SQL Azure writes into 3 places when committing to the database, but I was not sure about the export. Possibly there is 3 copies of the export file as well, although I see there is only one to import.

So how many copies of the DB are stored on an automated export?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure SQL Database Automated Export creates a single copy of your database, then exports the copy of the database to a single BACPAC file in Azure Storage. So you would have 1 BACPAC file per export operation.

The thing you would want to note is the redundancy of the storage you are using. For example locally redundant storage has 3 copies of the data maintained while geo-redundant storage has six copies of the data maintained. See Azure [storage redundancy options](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-redundancy/).

One other thing to note is you may not need to be doing Export at all, as all Basic, Standard, and Premium databases have built-in backups. There is a blog posts which discusses when to use the built in backups versus the export feature [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-built-in-backups-vs-importexport-2/). The built-in backups use RA-GRS storage which from the storage redundancy link shows there are six copies of the backups.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. So it seems there are 3 copies of data to fulfill the redundancy requirements, and since we use S2, then we get inbuilt backup as well with up to 6 copies of the data, going back 14 day, so 9 copies in total.

Comment: You'll also have the backups of the copied database until their retention runs out.